# dagger error binding with matching key exists in component

Tags: android, dagger-2

Dagger 2

```
/di/AppComponent.java:19: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ProductListFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: MainFragmentProvider_BindProductListFragment.ProductListFragmentSubcomponent
      ProductListFragment is injected at
          productlist.ProductListModule.provideChildFragmentManager(productListFragment)
      androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager is injected at
          productlist.adapter.NewProductListPagerAdapter(…, fragmentManager)
      productlist.adapter.NewProductListPagerAdapter is injected at
          productlist.ProductListV2Fragment.mPagerAdapter
      productlist.ProductListV2Fragment is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [di.AppComponent → di.BuilderModule_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent →  MainFragmentProvider_BindProductListV2Fragment.ProductListV2FragmentSubcomponent]
```

I have the following module with these 2 fragments here:

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentProvider {
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductListModule::class])
    abstract fun bindProductListV2Fragment(): ProductListV2Fragment
    
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductListModule::class])
    abstract fun bindProductListFragment(): ProductListFragment
}
```

In my ProductListModule I have the following:

```
@Module
class ProductListModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideChildFragmentManager(productListFragment: ProductListFragment) =
        productListFragment.childFragmentManager
}
```

The fragmentManager will be injected into the following class:

```
class NewProductListPagerAdapter @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val context: Context,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) { ..... }
```

And both fragments will inject this NewProductListPagerAdapter in them.

```
class ProductListV2Fragment  : BaseProductListFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPagerAdapter: NewProductListPagerAdapter
}

class ProductListFragment  : BaseProductListFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPagerAdapter: NewProductListPagerAdapter
}
```

My AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ProductModule::class,
        BaseAppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @BindsInstance application: Application,
        ): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(tsApplication: TsApplication)
}
```

==== UPDATE ====

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentProvider {

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductListModule::class, ProductListBindingModule::class])
    abstract fun bindProductListFragment(): ProductListFragment


    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductListModule::class, ProductListV2BindingModule::class])
    abstract fun bindProductListV2Fragment(): ProductListV2Fragment
}

@Module
class ProductListModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideChildFragmentManager(productListFragment: Fragment): FragmentManager =
        productListFragment.childFragmentManager
}


@Module
abstract class ProductListBindingModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFragment(fragment: ProductListFragment): Fragment
}

@Module
abstract class ProductListV2BindingModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFragment(fragment: ProductListV2Fragment): Fragment
}
```

The stack trace is below which is indicating that the Fragment is bound multiple times. The reason being is because each fragment injects the following dependency:

```
@Inject
lateinit var mPagerAdapter: NewProductListPagerAdapter
```

And in the NewProductListPagerAdapter constructor:

```
class NewProductListPagerAdapter @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val context: Context,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
)
```

Which needs to provide the FragmentManager;

```
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/uatDebug/tech/central/tops/di/AppComponent.java:22: error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] androidx.fragment.app.Fragment is bound multiple times:
public abstract interface AppComponent {
      @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Binds androidx.fragment.app.Fragment productlist.ProductListBindingModule.bindFragment(productlist.ProductListFragment)
      @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Binds androidx.fragment.app.Fragment productlist.ProductListV2BindingModule.bindFragment(productlist.ProductListV2Fragment)
      androidx.fragment.app.Fragment is injected at
          authentication.usecase.FacebookLoginUseCase(fragment, …)
      authentication.usecase.FacebookLoginUseCase is injected at
          authentication.usecase.SocialLoginUseCase(…, facebookLoginUseCase, …)
      authentication.usecase.SocialLoginUseCase is injected at
          authentication.FacebookLoginViewModel(…, socialLoginUseCase, …)
      authentication.FacebookLoginViewModel is injected at
          authentication.FacebookLoginViewModelModule.facebookViewModelChildFactory(facebookLoginViewModel)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          di.factory.ViewModelProviderFactory(classToViewModel)
      di.factory.ViewModelProviderFactory is injected at
          .authentication.login.LoginFragment.mViewModelChildFactory
      authentication.login.LoginFragment is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [tech.central.tops.di.AppComponent → di.BuilderModule_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent → FragmentProvider_BindLoginFragment.LoginFragmentSubcomponent]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your module depends on `ProductListFragment` to obtain a child `FragmentManager`.  However, that same module is used to inject into `ProductListV2Fragment`, and there is no `ProductListFragment` available at that point.

In order to reuse that module, you will need to split the dependency on `ProductListFragment` into a separate module.  This module should be used for `ProductListFragment`, and a similar module should be used for `ProductListV2Fragment`.  In these modules, you can either provide `FragmentManager` directly or bind both fragments to a common superclass such as `Fragment` or `BaseProductListFragment`.

If you bind both fragments to `Fragment`, the resulting code will look like this:

```kotlin
@Module
abstract class FragmentProvider {
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        ProductListModule::class,
        ProductListV2BindingModule::class
    ])
    abstract fun bindProductListV2Fragment(): ProductListV2Fragment
    
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        ProductListModule::class,
        ProductListBindingModule::class
    ])
    abstract fun bindProductListFragment(): ProductListFragment
}

@Module
class ProductListModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideChildFragmentManager(productListFragment: Fragment) =
        productListFragment.childFragmentManager
}

@Module
abstract class ProductListBindingModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindFragment(fragment: ProductListFragment): Fragment
}

@Module
abstract class ProductListV2BindingModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindFragment(fragment: ProductListV2Fragment): Fragment
}
```

As for the error message itself, it tells you three things:

- The generated `ProductListV2FragmentSubcomponent` requires a `ProductListFragment`, but there is no available binding for it.
- The subcomponent may be able to inject dependencies into an existing `ProductListFragment`.  This can be useful information in other situations, but it isn't relevant to what you're trying to do.
- There is a component in your app which *can* provide `ProductListFragment`.  Specifically, this is the generated `ProductListFragmentSubcomponent`, which takes a `ProductListFragment` in its factory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, after implementing it I have another bound `multiple times error` I have updated my question with an update and the reason I think why. However, I think with only code snippets it might be more difficult to solve.